# Create database command failing

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, smo

I have an active SMO connection

```
        string server = textBox_Server.Text;
        ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection(server);
        // Log in using SQL authentication instead of Windows authentication
        srvConn.LoginSecure = false;
        // Give the login username
        srvConn.Login = textBox_userName.Text;
        // Give the login password
        srvConn.Password = textBox_Password.Text;
        // Create a new SQL Server object using the connection we created
         srvSql = new Server(srvConn);
```

I can see there existing databases and their information.
But when I try to create a new database

```
 Database myDatabase = new Database(srvSql, "MyNewDatabase");
  myDatabase.Create();
```

I am getting an FailedOperationExeption , any idea why ? what i am doing wrong when i create a new database . And how i can solve it ...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the failed operation have an inner exception? They  usually do with more information.

If not, try running the profiler on the SQL server and examine the commands .Net executing and the responses the server sends back...

Comment: found solution for my problem it's w7_64 problem

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/861b57bc-aa21-4b03-bd01-5c164e2bac4e